# Help identifying a decapped IC chip

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification, die

I have a 24 pin IC chip that was soldered onto a tiny PCB. I was able to decap the chip and read the label, but I am not finding any information through Google.

Does anyone recognize this label that can help me narrow down either the part number or who the manufacturer is?

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV8jx.jpg

[image]

Comment: What was written on it before you decapped it? That tends to be easier to use to identify chips.

Comment: Context is everything. You'll need to at least provide details about the size of the IC (was it TQPF or TSSOP or other shape), and what circuit it was used it.

Comment: TI might be Texas Instruments. The "m" logo might be Motorola (but doesn't look much like it). Anyhow the function of the chip may help greatly with identification, if you can share that. E.g. if you suspect it's a MEMS accelerometer or something like that.

Comment: @7786 - Hi, Why did you tag this "microcontroller"? Do you have evidence of the device being one of those? As others have said, context helps. Thanks. (FYI, if you have an image of the whole die, please add that - either here, if < 2MB, or on Imgur if larger, and we can add a reduced version here - since there is a chance to guess some details depending on the structures that are visible e.g. digital or analog sections.)

Comment: _"Does anyone recognize this label"_ - what label??? Why do you need to identify it?

Comment: 7786 - Hi, I have flagged this for mod attention, as you keep deleting the image from the question, even after a mod rolled-back your edit which removed it, and I want to avoid escalating the "edit war" by doing yet another rollback myself. IMHO that image is an important part of the question, and deleting it could be considered as vandalism of the question. I urge you to, please, reinstate the image. Thanks.

Comment: 7786 - The Imgur link you just added back, now does not show a photo. Please can you explain why you are deleting (or adding non-working links to) the photo? Are you having problems with using this site? Or does the photo cause you some kind of problem, and you don't want people to see it? What is happening?! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's going to be very hard to determine with any great certainty, but I would suggest Texas Instruments [MSP430FR5738](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas639l/slas639l.pdf) microcontroller as a possibility. Though it is questionable.

If you could provide further details/pictures of the board itself and get an idea of some of the connections/functionality that would help.

---

My reasoning:

The `(m)` appears to be the [US standard copyright symbol for a set of IC masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit_layout_design_protection) - Ⓜ.  Thanks @SamGibson for pointing that out.

The first line - `2010TI` - reads to me as a year, 2010, and then could suggest the company - `TI` would be Texas Instruments (This has been confirmed by @AlexanderStohr's answer).

That leaves `NM5739`, which doesn't match anything particularly sensible. But then to be honest I wouldn't expect it to, die numbering is generally entirely internal, and there is no reason to suspect it will match the actual part number. But lets assume that it does.

The only part that TI sells with a number containing 5739 is the MSP430 series of microcontrollers. You've tagged it with microcontroller, but that might just be bad tagging.

Of these, the `5739` series number is unfortunately not in the correct package - its a 40pin QFN. However, the `5738` is in a 24pin QFN package -- "RGE". The RGE package is 4mm x 4mm and 6 pins on each side. That matches.

Now as far as I can tell, the only difference between a `5739` and a `5738` is the number of available IO pins. It stands to reason that TI might use the same die for both to save costs, and for the smaller packages simply not bother to wire out some of the pins. This is quite a common thing to do. And from your picture it appears that there are pads which are not pinned out, though perhaps the bonds may have been lost during decapitation (?).

Furthermore, the datasheet for this series was released June 2011. If we assume a period of development before hand, it stands to reason that 2010 would be an apt year for it.

Comment: Hi Tom, Just FYI the "M in a circle" symbol is explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit_layout_design_protection) Wikipedia article. Your analysis of the rest certainly seems *very plausible*, agreed! I'm hoping to see more evidence to analyse from the OP, on a full die photo.

Comment: @SamGibson thought it might be something like that, but never come across the (m) one before. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

The internal chip markings are mostly internal to the chip vendors.
Especially the sequence from the last row might never seen publishing (as if for the lot numbers of industrial packaged foods, cosmetics and medicaments.)

Luckily i can provide you (from the internet) a reference that bears a similar engraving.
[image]

source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Die-marking-on-a-TI-65nm-processor-Quirk-2013_fig6_301317714

As you can see it has those M in the circle, a years number with the same TI suffix and this 3rd line. Additionally there is an upside down placed logo of Texas Instruments. (That far its /free form/ and not part of any general scheme.)

With the rough description you gave in the comments section i would guess that chip to be maybe a USB chipset, an interface driver, a motor driver, some power controller or just analog devices. (TI claims to be the largest supplier of analog integrated circuit of the world.)

Don't you have a full size image of the die? Just for curiosity - but not expecting it to help much for now - unless it resembles some of the often published (or reverse engineered) die images of mainstream processors and MCUs.

If your intentions are good enough (e.g. fraudulent cases to unveil) then you might try to contact TI for providing you a statement on the chip to the needed degree. They should be able to look it up.